# Encoder/Decoder PCM to AMR Android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, pcm, amr

I've been looking for a while now for any java library that allows me to **encode and decode** a PCM-AMR audio stream that is sent through a TCP socket connection. Without having to use Android's JNI.

Is there anything that can help me?

In the worst case scenario. How can I do it using any C++ library with JNI? (any reference of how to use ffmpeg with JNI will be appreciated)

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Note that pcm usually means RAW and note encoded downstream of the microphone (hardware ) that generated the signal. amr-nb, amr-wb are encoded. So, i suggest that you resolve exactly what type of bytestream that you have on the socket..

Then, IMO , on android, ffmpeg libs provide robust , wide choice of TO/FROM Codecs and the way to convert.

See any of the main github [android-ffmpeg] projects, acouple of which are below:

[guardian](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg)

[halfninja](https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264)

Its a bit of learn curve to sort thru all the JNI/Android stuff. IMO if you are doing low-level media stuff like this , you have little alternate to mastering JNI.