# AMR codec Native Support in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, native, codec, amr

Is there any way to Support Amr Codec, As of now for research, using WASAPI and XAudio2 APIs i didn't able to find anything most intesting that is telling Amr supported.
but microsoft supported codec seen below link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx

i believe that AMR codec suppport is present in windows phone. anybody help me how i can able to use AMR codec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question in Microsoft forum and i got the answer,
the answer is Microsoft doesn't support in-build AMR codec, to support AMR codec in windows phone we need to use Third Party Codec Library.

refer this link anybody has same question:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/28e2bc65-e938-4256-b8ee-43affe556666/is-it-possible-to-use-media-extension-for-encoding-raw-audio-pcm-data-to-amr-data?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can get it with windows phone. It does support AMR codec. I don't think you have to do anything to be able to use it. This website has more information on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks bobtheboy, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx this link doesnt specify anything about how to use amr codec. if you can tell me how to use amr codec it will be great help. Thanks,

Comment: Here is some information on it that I have found so far: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_audio_codec#Usage

Comment: i want to know about windows phone API to encode PCM to AMR, Do you have any idea?

Comment: Here is what I think you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167663/encoder-decoder-pcm-to-amr-android (it is for android though)